Screen goes blank after chakra-ui modal code added
I have a navbar which has a button to open modal, which is a component. I added the chakra-ui code as seen in docs and after that the whole screen disappears when i remove the code the app appears again.
Navbar
import { Box, Container, Flex, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { useColorMode, useColorModeValue } from "./ui/color-mode";
import { IoMoon } from "react-icons/io5";
import { LuSun } from "react-icons/lu";
import React from "react";
import CreateUserModal from "./CreateUserModal";

const Navbar = () => {
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();
  return (
    <Container maxW={"900px"}>
      <Box
        px={4}
        my={4}
        borderRadius={5}
        bg={useColorModeValue("gray.200", "gray.700")}
      >
        <Flex h="16" alignItems={"center"} justifyContent={"space-between"}>
          {/* Left side */}
          <Flex
            alignItems={"center"}
            justifyItems={"center"}
            gap={3}
            display={{ base: "none", sm: "flex" }}
          >
            <img src="/react.png" alt="React logo" width={50} height={50} />
            <Text fontSize={"40px"}>+</Text>
            <img src="/python.png" alt="Python logo" width={50} height={40} />
            <Text fontSize={"40px"}>=</Text>
            <img src="/explode.png" alt="Explode logo" width={45} height={45} />
          </Flex>
          {/* Right side */}
          <Flex gap={3} alignItems={"center"}>
            <Text
              fontSize={"lg"}
              fontWeight={500}
              display={{ base: "none", md: "block" }}
            >
              BFFship 
            </Text>
            <Button onClick={toggleColorMode}>
              {colorMode === "light" ? <IoMoon /> : <LuSun size={20} />}
            </Button>
            <CreateUserModal />
          </Flex>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

CreateUserModal
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { BiAddToQueue } from "react-icons/bi";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalCloseButton,
  ModalBody,
  Flex,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Input,
  useDisclosure,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

function CreateUserModal() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>
        <BiAddToQueue size={20} />
      </Button>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody pb={6}>
            <Flex alignItems={"center"} gap={4}>
              <FormControl>
                <FormLabel>Full Name</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="John Doe" />
              </FormControl>
            </Flex>
          </ModalBody>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreateUserModal;


I tried checking the app.jsx tried chatgpt, tried writting the code again from scratch but nothing.

are you using chakra 3.0 or old 2.10.4?

I'm using 3.0. The problem is solved now.
